# Why do I have to have CapsLock permanently ON

Tags: capslock

Initially, I believed this was on **OpenOffice** problem but **Abiword** and, indeed, **Gedit**, display the same problem, so it must be an Ubuntu glitch.

I was typing a document and used CapsLock when creating a title. Now, when I turn CapsLock off, **everything** is in caps - when I turn it on, everything is in lower case. I can cope with this if I leave CapsLock on permanently but this is *not* what is supposed to happen. CapsLock OFF = NO CAPS (or should do!).

Can anybody help with this? I've searched around this forum but, not being much of a forum user, I was unable to find a solution. It's entirely possible that I had a 'finger-fit' and hit a combo of buttons which included CapsLock but I don't remember doing that.

I'm running Ubuntu Netbook Edition 10.04 on an HP Intel PC. If you need any more System specific stuff, just shout.

Thanks, 
Patrick

P.S. As a quick addendum to this item, the situation doesn't survive a reboot. All is again normal when the PC is restarted - I just don't want to have to reboot every time it happens. I'd get nothing done! P.M.

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens when your hardware does not properly detect a key release (I have seen this 
happen under Windows too) as the software you use automatically changes the state of the capslock.
So it only affects the light on your system.

Some solutions...

- [You can change the light from command line with](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_setleds.htm)

  ```
  setleds +caps
  setleds -caps
  ```
- You can also reset it from the software you use. If you let it autocorrect again it will fix itself too. So type `hELLO` and after it changes to `Hello` the light is not switched again too so is corrected.
- Do not use autocorrection in the software you use.